# How to get my casted variable to round correctly?

Tags: sql, casting

The results when I run this are 0.0000 or 1.0000. So it is rounding when I don't want it to. Any idea how to fix this?

```
Cast((Var1Count)/cast(TotalCount as decimal(10,4)) as decimal(10,4)) as Var1Percent
```

I also tried

```
Cast(cast(Var1Count as decimal(10,4))/cast(TotalCount as decimal(10,4)) as decimal(10,4)) as Var1Percent
```

Comment: It kooks like your data column is auto-filling zeros. Please post information about your exact SQL set up and your exact column setup. Cheers

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I suspect the correct value is 0 or 1 and you are misinterpreting the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does a perfect job in my case.

Tried Vertica and PostreSQL.

What input do you need to trigger the issue?

```
WITH
indata(var1count,totalcount) AS (
            SELECT   3,    10
  UNION ALL SELECT 100,314159
)
SELECT
  *
, CAST(
     (var1count)/cast(totalcount AS DECIMAL(10,4)) 
   AS DECIMAL(10,4)
  ) AS var1percent
FROM indata;
-- PostgreSQL
-- out  var1count | totalcount | var1percent 
-- out -----------+------------+-------------
-- out          3 |         10 |      0.3000
-- out        100 |     314159 |      0.0003
--
-- Vertica
-- out  var1count | totalcount | var1percent 
-- out -----------+------------+-------------
-- out          3 |         10 |      0.3000
-- out        100 |     314159 |      0.0003
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, this seems strange.  The first should produce a decimal result.

Does this do what you want?

```
Var1Count * 1.0 / TotalCount
```